# PySide6 QCalendarWidget Qss style problem with month names

Tags: qtstylesheets, qcalendarwidget

i have a weird problem with qss styling an QCalendarWidget
The months names get overlapped by the menu indicator.
Anyone have an idea why?

[image: problem]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in its stylesheet:

```
#qt_calendar_monthbutton::menu-indicator{
   width:0px;
}
```

This removes the big arrow that overlaps the month name